# Caching across protocol by using //:domain.com - is it possible?

Tags: php, symfony

I believe the recommended way these days is to serve static files from a domain using //domain.com rather then http://domain.com and https://domain.com as needed. In fact https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide lists snippets in this format.

My question is, does this or any method allow caching across http/https? I thought it did (can't remember why) but my testing doesn't seem to allow me to do it. The problem is I recently changed a number of things about my setup (server, PHP framework) and so can't be sure why I cant cache across http/https (unless of course it isn't possible).

I'm wondering which of the methods is best to include static files:

(1) Serve exactly http or https depending on the page requested

(2) use //domain.com

(3) Always use https to serve static content, even on http pages as that way it will only donwnload once, but of course first visit to a site uses https for static content which can be slow, but at least it won't download files twice.

I know there's an issue in IE7 and 8 with stylesheets by using the //domain.com method though.

Any help, and particularly is it possible to cache across protocol as when a user first uses a https page for the first time it's really slow (until everything's cached) and I want to stop that.

Answer (score 0):

On a server that supports both http and https you should probably reference assets via https if possible. This will maximize the caching and avoid any mixed content errors.  Another motivation is that tomorrow [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Site_Compatibility_for_Firefox_23#Non-SSL_contents_on_SSL_pages_are_blocked_by_default) is going to start happening with the release of FF 23. Basically in an ssl context the browser will not download non-ssl assets.